# Oracle ADF Url Ip address not work

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have an oracle ADF application in oracle jdeveloper 11g and the output url in browser is :

```
http://127.0.0.1:7101/centralbank-ViewController-context-root/faces/untitled1.jsf?_adf.ctrl-state=tqdhpayew_27
```

but when i want to use my ip network address which is 192.168.1.53 instead of 127.0.0.1 , i can not see the output page .
What am i missing ?

Comment: Why do you want to use your IP address?

Comment: Because I have an IP static and route it into 192.168.1.53 and I want to share my application on web

Answer (score 0):

Go into the weblogic console and check which address the listener is listening on.
...:7101/console

You can set it to be empty to listen to both 127.0.0.1 and your real ip

Comment: Thanks about your reply , but i do that and i set the listen address to empty and its listen port is 7001 and my application running on 7101 port number , but i can not see this application with my ip address .

Comment: Check your servise listening address with `netstat -na`. If it there and not bound only to 127.0.0.1, then it might be firewall issue or something like that.